# find equation of a line perpendicular to the given line through the given point

Tags: graphing-functions

> Find equation of a line perpendicular to the given line through the given point:
> The line is $y=\frac{1}{2}x-2$
> The point is $(3,6)$

I don't know what to do or try, please help me, its probably very easy to other people

Comment: Until you learn LaTeX, you should use parentheses to make things clear. If you mean $\frac{1}{2}x-2$, you should write something like (1/2)(x)-2. If you mean $\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$ you should write (1/2)(x-2).

Comment: I don't even know what your talkin about but is the answer y=2x+12

Comment: No it isn't. The slope of the given line is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the slope of the perpendicular is $-2$. The equation has therefore shape $y=-2x+b$. Put $x=3$, $y=6$. So $6=(-2)(3)+b$, and therefore $b=12$. So the equation is $y=-2x+12$.

Comment: oh I thought I said that

Comment: You left out the minus sign.

Comment: oh okay thanks, I was wondering if you could help me on my newer math problem its a word problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slope of given line is : $m_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

If two lines are perpendicular, then the product of their slopes is $-1$. Exception being the lines are $x$ and $y$ axes which is not the case here. hence:

$$m_1*m_2 = -1$$
$$\frac{1}{2} * m_2 = -1$$
$$ m_2 = -2$$
Now calculate the line equation of line with slope = $-2$ and passing through point $(3,6)$.
$$(y-6) = -2(x-3)$$
$$2x + y = 12$$
$$ y = -2x + 12$$

Comment: umm what am supposed to do

Comment: What do you mean ? The final equation above is the required equation of the line perpendicular to the given line.

Comment: so final answer is y=2x+12 in y=mx+b form

Comment: No. its is $y = -2x+12$.

Comment: can you help me with my newer math problem, its  word problem please